# Inner template classes inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I have the following code: https://gist.github.com/PatrikValkovic/50329975f86e0328ff1f85fda17a23f3, live example here: http://cpp.sh/675a3.

In short, I have class A with inner class B<U> and class D that should inherit from the B<U>. The code works when the class D is declared within class A (as commented). However, when I move the declaration outside of the class A (as in the example), the compiler complains, that `A<T>::B<U>` is not a type. What is wrong about the syntax?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    class B;    

    /*
    class D : public B<int>
    {
    public:
        void method2() {
            cout << "Method 2" << endl;
            this->method1();
        }
    };
    */

    class D;
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
class A<T>::B 
{
public:
    void method1() {
        T x;
        cout << "Method 1: " << x << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class A<T>::D : public A<T>::B<int>
{
public:
    void method2() {
        cout << "Method 2" << endl;
        this->method1();
    }
};

int main()
{
  A<int>::D b;
  b.method2();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those really weird edge cases in the C++ language that has a unusual fix. The issue is here:

```
template<typename T>
class A<T>::D : public A<T>::B<int>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The problem is that you are trying to use the template class `B`, which is a dependent name inside of `A` (that is, `B` is a template nested inside another type that depends on a template argument, here, `T`). By default, C++ won't treat dependent names as being names of types or names of templates, and you have to explicitly tell the compiler "yes, this is the name of a template" by using the `template` keyword in an unusual way:

```
template<typename T>
class A<T>::D : public A<T>::template B<int>
                             ^^^^^^^^
```

This tells C++ "inside of `A<T>`, you're going to find a template type named `B`. Please use that template with argument `int`."

This is similar to how you have to use the `typename` keyword with dependent types - it tells the compiler "yes, this is the name of a type." Here, the `template` keyword tells the compiler "yes, this is the name of a template."

Comment: Holy sh*t. Never seen using `template` keyword such way (although I was surprised by template template arguments as well). I guess one never fully knows C++. The question arises - do we really want to use such a complicated language? But that's out of scope of the question. You answer works, thank you very much.

Comment: Why does `A<T>` not refer to the current instantiation? If it does, then I think that `A<T>::B<int>` should be correct, because "in the definition of a class template, a nested class of a class template, a member of a class template, or a member of a nested class of a class template, the injected-class-name of the class template or nested class,". So, because `B` is a member of the current instantiation `A<T>`, it looks to me as though  `::template` is not required?

Comment: Further investigation with `clang` indicates that I might be right. GCC disagrees with Clang and me. However, I strongly suspect that GCC wrongly rejects his code (although I will admit I've not been in touch with this subject for some time now).